# fullPage.js Why don't work scroll? If remove any tags or styles - worked

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, fullpage.js

Why don't scroll work when height is less than 500px? And what could be the solution?

Check the [Example](http://shadow.perm.ru/test/obl/index.html).

If I remove any tag, style or comment the `scrollOverflow`, it works.

I'm using **Chrome 42.0.2311.82 beta-m (64-bit)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are disabling the auto-scroll. Don't know if you intend that..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fullpage').fullpage({
        css3: true,
        autoScrolling: false, // here ...
        scrollOverflow: true,
        sectionsColor: ['#e6e6e6', '#e6e6e6']
    });

});
```

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#fullpage').fullpage({
            css3: true,
            autoScrolling: true,
            scrollOverflow: true,
            sectionsColor: ['#e6e6e6', '#e6e6e6']
    });
});
```

This way the auto-scroll from fullPage works.

When the height is less than `500px` it still works. If you want normal scroll less than 500px do this:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#fullpage').fullpage({
            css3: true,
            autoScrolling: true,
            scrollOverflow: true,
            sectionsColor: ['#e6e6e6', '#e6e6e6'],
            responsive: 500
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks. There is no solution for it.

https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/553